# Buggy interface for audience

Tags: release-freya, audience

When I open a video then interface split into two one with title of the video I am playing, with seek-bar and other controls and another with audience where it plays video which I can't make full-screen

[image]

```
(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: apps.css:141:26: 'none' is not a valid color name

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: apps.css:239:20: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backgrounds.css:15:22: Not a valid image

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backgrounds.css:100:22: Not a valid image

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-assets.css:41:18: Expected a number

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2:19: Theming engine 'adwaita' not found

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:396:22: Not a valid image

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:541:0: '' is not a valid color name

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1296:25: Missing name of pseudo-class

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2122:24: Junk at end of value

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2402:18: Not a valid image

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2551:22: Not a valid image

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2671:22: Not a valid image

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2678:22: Not a valid image

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2732:22: Not a valid image

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2738:22: Not a valid image

(audience:5152): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:3637:4: Junk at end of value
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:55:29.189266] Application.vala:155: Audience version: 0.1.0.2
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 18:55:29.189323] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.16.0-43-generic
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.190793] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2:19: Theming engine 'adwaita' not found
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.191619] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:396:22: Not a valid image
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.191964] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:541:0: '' is not a valid color name
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.193028] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1296:25: Missing name of pseudo-class
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.194524] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2122:24: Junk at end of value
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.194949] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2402:18: Not a valid image
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.195394] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2551:22: Not a valid image
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.195644] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2671:22: Not a valid image
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.195721] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2678:22: Not a valid image
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.195878] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2732:22: Not a valid image
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.195941] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2738:22: Not a valid image
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.197368] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:3637:4: Junk at end of value
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.199239] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backgrounds.css:15:22: Not a valid image
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.199421] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backgrounds.css:100:22: Not a valid image
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.199894] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-borders.css:75:22: 'none' is not a valid color name
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.201781] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-overrides.css:630:0: not a number
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:29.201841] [Gtk] Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-overrides.css:630:0: expected '}' after declarations
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.219203] [Gtk] Connecting to session manager
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.225816] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.audience'
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.227705] [GLib-GObject] g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.227737] Audience will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.229058] VideoPlayer.vala:497: Updating subtitle font
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.256532] [GLib-GObject] g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.256586] Audience will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358106] DiskManager.vala:103: Check DVD media for: SONGS
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358175] DiskManager.vala:107: Activation root: file:///home/eshant/Music
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358320] DiskManager.vala:103: Check DVD media for: MOVIES
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358364] [GLib-GIO] g_mount_get_default_location: assertion 'G_IS_MOUNT (mount)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358385] Audience will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358416] DiskManager.vala:103: Check DVD media for: EXTRA
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358443] [GLib-GIO] g_mount_get_default_location: assertion 'G_IS_MOUNT (mount)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358466] Audience will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358492] DiskManager.vala:103: Check DVD media for: Windows7
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358518] [GLib-GIO] g_mount_get_default_location: assertion 'G_IS_MOUNT (mount)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358538] Audience will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358562] DiskManager.vala:103: Check DVD media for: Backup
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358605] [GLib-GIO] g_mount_get_default_location: assertion 'G_IS_MOUNT (mount)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358624] Audience will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358648] DiskManager.vala:103: Check DVD media for: L_CENTER
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358674] [GLib-GIO] g_mount_get_default_location: assertion 'G_IS_MOUNT (mount)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358693] Audience will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358717] DiskManager.vala:103: Check DVD media for: L-STORE
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358745] DiskManager.vala:107: Activation root: file:///media/L-Store
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358852] DiskManager.vala:103: Check DVD media for: W-STORE
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358881] [GLib-GIO] g_mount_get_default_location: assertion 'G_IS_MOUNT (mount)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 18:55:29.358901] Audience will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358925] DiskManager.vala:103: Check DVD media for: VIDEOS
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:29.358953] DiskManager.vala:107: Activation root: file:///home/eshant/Videos
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:37.757717] [Gtk] Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/themes/Xenite/gtk-3.0/css/dark/assets/pane-separator-grip-dark.svg': Error opening file: No such file or directory
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:37.789707] [Gtk] Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/themes/Xenite/gtk-3.0/css/dark/borders/button-border-dark.png': Error opening file: No such file or directory
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:37.790411] [Gtk] Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/themes/Xenite/gtk-3.0/css/dark/borders/button-border-default-dark.png': Error opening file: No such file or directory
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:37.791673] [Gtk] Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/themes/Xenite/gtk-3.0/css/dark/borders/generic-border-dark.png': Error opening file: No such file or directory
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 18:55:58.431598] [Gtk] Error loading image 'file:///usr/share/themes/Xenite/gtk-3.0/css/dark/borders/generic-border-focused-dark.png': Error opening file: No such file or directory
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:58.676533] Audience.vala:834: Opening file:///home/eshant/Learning/Python/python%20tutorial%20advanced%20-%20YouTube/Python%20Advanced%20Tutorial%203%20-%20Argparse%20(720p).mp4
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:55:58.768452] VideoPlayer.vala:497: Updating subtitle font
15 56 15,37
Width: 1250.000000, Height: 703.125000, Offset: 75.000000 (1280.000000, 720.000000)
Result: 1280 2105 == 1280 779
15 56 15,37
Width: 1245.000000, Height: 700.312500, Offset: 75.000000 (1280.000000, 720.000000)
Result: 1275 2096 == 1275 776
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:56:03.173830] VideoPlayer.vala:497: Updating subtitle font
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:56:03.174358] VideoPlayer.vala:497: Updating subtitle font
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:56:03.174594] Audience.vala:683: saving settings for: file:///home/eshant/Learning/Python/python%20tutorial%20advanced%20-%20YouTube/Python%20Advanced%20Tutorial%203%20-%20Argparse%20(720p).mp4
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:56:03.174736] VideoPlayer.vala:497: Updating subtitle font
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 18:56:03.174903] VideoPlayer.vala:497: Updating subtitle font
```

Is it due to Gtk theme I am using([Xenite](https://github.com/eOS-themes/Xenite))?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't see the issue using the default theme then it's a Xenite issue. Since I [don't develop this theme anymore](https://github.com/eOS-themes/Xenite/blob/master/readme.md#note-this-theme-is-no-longer-under-development-hopefully-we-developers--contributors-will-back-on-this-theme-soon-but-not-before-the-date-of-elementary-os-04-release), I won't fix that even if it's an issue with the theme.

Comment: no it's not a theme issue

Answer (score 2):

For me, the culprit was gstreamer1.0-clutter.
Installing Totem with its dependencies fixed my problem and by uninstalling package with package, I came to gstreamer1.0-clutter.﻿

Hope it helps ...